# With Firebase Analytics how do I see breakdown by specific iOS version? (eg iOS 11.1.3, iOS 12.2.1)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

If I go to my Firebase Analytics Dashboard, there's a "platform breakdown" pie chart that just says "100% iOS".

If I go to "Filter" at the top I can choose each specific version of iOS, but it's super tedious because at a high level I just want to see which version of iOS is being used the most by users.

It's an iOS only app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the Dashboard under the header "*What's your audience like?*" which shows a map with where your users are from, you can instead choose the tab "*Devices*" where you can see the percentage of users on each of your top OS versions.

[image]